# Adding XML Catalog contributions programmatically

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-wtp

How can I add new entries to Eclipse's XML Catalog programmatically (instead of using `org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.catalogContributions` extension point)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no API for doing this.  That's why there is an extension point.